# C# How to implement CSV file into this code

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, replace, find

Hi I am fairly new to coding, I have a piece of code that searches for a string and replaces it with another string like so:

```
var replacements = new[]{
   new{Find="123",Replace="Word one"},
   new{Find="ABC",Replace="Word two"},
   new{Find="999",Replace="Word two"},
};

var myLongString = "123 is a long 999 string yeah";

foreach(var set in replacements)
{
   myLongString = myLongString.Replace(set.Find, set.Replace);
}
```

If I want to use a CSV file that contains a lot of words and their replacements, for example, LOL,Laugh Out Loud, and ROFL, Roll Around Floor Laughing. How would I implement that?

Comment: Why CSV format?

Comment: if you read them in and have old, new <newline> it would be a sinch and Im sure something you could work out for yourself

Comment: using value pairs like that i would use a dictionary, essentially a key-value pair, which is what you have

Comment: Read in your CSV file (and this can be any format, really, in fact, json would work very nicely here) into a dictionary and iterate through the dictionary just as you do with the 'replacements' object.

Comment: You're getting all these random suggestions because you're asking too many questions; you're new, you want to search strings, you want to replace strings, you want to read CSV files. Work on one step at a time. If you have a problem with one step, ask specifically about that step.

Comment: What does that code have to do with the question of writing a CSV?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: If you are going to use "a lot of words", you will get better performance, etc. from using `StringBuilder.Replace` than from using `string.Replace`.  If you can guarantee that none of your fields have embedded commas, then you can just read in the lines and use `string.Split` to split things up.  You may be happier using a "tab-separated" file rather than a comma separated file (the likelihood of embedded tabs is pretty low) (or pipe-separated (`|`), or something else that would never be used)

Comment: Sorry, I was just using the code above to show what I was looking to be done. I am researching how to do this as well as reading the comments above. It seems to me that some people on here like to criticise more than help with suggestion. Perhaps those people should just no bother to comment if they dont want to help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a text file that looks like (you could use commas, but I like pipes (`|`)):

```
123|Word One
ABC|Word Two
999|Word Three
LOL|Laugh Out Loud
ROFL|Roll Around Floor Laughing
```

Then create a tiny helper class:

```
public class WordReplace
{
    public string Find { get; set; }
    public string Replace { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, call this code:

```
private static string  DoWordReplace()
{
    //first read in the data
    var fileData = File.ReadAllLines("WordReplace.txt");
    var wordReplacePairs = new List<WordReplace>();
    var lineNo = 1;
    foreach (var item in fileData)
    {
        var pair = item.Split(new[] {'|'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (pair.Length != 2)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException($"Malformed file, line {lineNo}, data = [{item}] ");
        }
        wordReplacePairs.Add(new WordReplace{Find = pair[0], Replace = pair[1]});
        ++lineNo;
    }

    var longString = "LOL, 123 is a long 999 string yeah, ROFL";

    //now do the replacements
    var buffer = new StringBuilder(longString);
    foreach (var pair in wordReplacePairs)
    {
        buffer.Replace(pair.Find, pair.Replace);
    }

    return buffer.ToString();
}
```

The result is:

```
Laugh Out Loud, Word One is a long Word Three string yeah, Roll Around Floor Laughing
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) I will give this a try and adapt it to my code.

Comment: @GZoid.  Oops, I forgot a bit of code (the `WordReplace` helper class).  Take a look at my update.  If this works for you, don't forget to accept it.

Comment: Flydog57, thank you. Your code really helped point me in the right direction. With some clues from that I was able to get exactly what I needed. Its helpful people like yourself that make this site :) I took my time to understand it and break it down. Thanks again.

Comment: @GZoid: Thanks for the "Thanks" and for the acknowledgement that "Its helpful people like yourself that make this site". But that's not how this site works. To "make this site" you need to accept or up-vote answers that help you